# How to create a document within a collection, with the same name as the unique authorized User UID?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I wrote a component that allows registration for the user.
The user enters an email, password, name and phone number.
Entering the email and password will enable registration (I used auth.service and registerWithEmail).
 After registration **new user with a unique User UID will be created** on the Authentication page in firebase:
[image: picture of the Authentication page in firebase]

I would like to create a situation where the details "name" and "phone" that the user entered, will be saved in a **document with the same name as the User UID**, in a collection called "user-info".
[image: picture of the cloud firestore page in firebase]
**My Problem:** The name of the document created is different from the unique User UID name.
**In other words:** I want the id marked in green in the image to be the id marked in red

*The relevant code from **crud.service.ts**:*

```
  create_userInfo(RecordUserInfo)
  { 
    return this.fireservices.collection('users').doc(this.authservice.currentUserId).collection('user-info').add(RecordUserInfo);
  }
```

*The relevant code from **register.component.ts**:*

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  email="";
  password="";
  name="";
  phone="";
  message = '';
  errorMessage = ''; //validation error handle
  error: {name:string, message:string} = {name:'' , message:''}; //firebase error handle
  
  constructor(private authservice: AuthService, private router: Router, public crudservice:CrudService) { }

  ngOnInit(){ 
  }

  CreateRecordUserInfo()
  {
    if(this.authservice.currentUser != null)//We will make sure the user is logged in
    {
      let RecordUserInfo = {};
      RecordUserInfo['name'] = this.name;
      RecordUserInfo['email'] = this.email;
      RecordUserInfo['phone'] = this.phone;

      this.crudservice.create_userInfo(RecordUserInfo).then(res => {
        this.name = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.phone = "";
        this.message = "user-info data save done";
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
  }

  register()
  {
    this.clearErrorMessage();
    if(this.validateForm(this.email, this.password, this.name, this.phone))
    {
      this.authservice.registerWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
      .then(() => {

        //we will save the user-info in collection named 'user-info'
        this.CreateRecordUserInfo();

        this.message = "Your data is registered in firebase"
        this.router.navigate(['/home-page'])
      }).catch(_error =>{
        this.error = _error
        this.router.navigate(['/register'])
      })
    }
  }
```

*The relevant code from **auth.service.ts**:*

```
export class AuthService {
  authState: any =null;
  constructor(private afu: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.afu.authState.subscribe((auth =>{
      this.authState = auth;
    }))
  }

  //function in use in register.component.ts
  registerWithEmail(email: string, password: string){
    return this.afu.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      this.authState = user
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      })
  }

  //get fanctions, to get data from firebase
  get isUserAnonymousLoggedIn(): boolean{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false
  } 
  get currentUserId(): string{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.uid : ''
  } 
  get currentUserName(): string{
    return this.authState['email']
  } 
  get currentUser(): any{
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState : null;
  } 
  get isUserEmailLoggedIn(): boolean{
    if((this.authState !== null) && (!this.isUserAnonymousLoggedIn)){
      return true
    } else{
      return false
    }
  }
```

My guess is that I call the function `this.CreateRecordUserInfo();` in a problematic place, so that the registration itself is not finished yet. Do you have an idea how to solve the problem?
many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
  registerWithEmail(email: string, password: string){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.afu.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((credential) => {
        this.authState = credential.user;
        resolve(credential.user);
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
        throw error;
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it did not work, but I edited my question and added pictures to it that would better explain my intent.

Comment: The id of the document is still not uid. it could be that the problem is in the location where I call the function: `this.CreateRecordUserInfo();` in register.component.ts file? @N.F.

Comment: I have update my answer again. You have to return new `Promise` in your  `registerWithEmail`.

Comment: Interesting, probably this was part of the problem, but the document sill doesn't has the uid name @N.F.

Comment: Can you show me the result of `console.log(this.authservice.currentUser)` just before you call `this.CreateRecordUserInfo();` ?

Comment: and the result of `console.log(this.authservice.currentUserId)` just before I call `this.CreateRecordUserInfo();` is `undefined`  @N.F.

Comment: `this.afu.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.password).then`  resolves `UserCredential`. You should set `credential.user` to `this.authState`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: there is a problem with the line  `resolve(user);` @N.F.

Comment: I have fixed the line.